# Asus F5N laptop built-in card reader driver problem

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, card-reader

I have an Asus F5N X50N-AP011C. I have manually installed Windows 7 x64 on it, replacing the original Windows Vista. It also automatically installed a card reader driver, but it can no longer read xD cards. The driver shows in the device manager as "Generic- xD/SDMMC/MS/Pro USB device" (under "drives" - and a drive is also shown in Windows Explorer). The same card reader once used to work with xD cards. I also tried to manually install drivers from this website: http://www.station-drivers.com/page/realtek.htm - the RTS 5158 but it didn't work (it shows as USB device in device manager, but not as a drive in Windows Explorer).

Does anyone know

- what card reader my model has built-in? (I think it's the 5158 but I don't know how to verify that - there's also no hint in the System Information tool, only the driver name is listed under "drives")
- how it is connected internally?
- if there is a better Windows 7 x64 driver?

Answer (score 0):

In Device Manager, check the Properties for the device.  Under the Details tab, you should have drop-down options for Device ID, Hardware ID and such.  Plug those into Google, and you should be able to find the proper model numbers and drivers you need.

Comment: Thanks, but the only info in there is the generic driver info from the Windows system driver. Nothing hardware specific. `Device Class GUID = {4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}, Hardware ID = USBSTOR\DiskGeneric-xD/SDMMC/MS/Pro_1.00` and similar.

Answer (score 0):

You should always try the drivers provided by the manufacturer first, whether it be for the whole computer or individual hardware. I do not consider sites such as Station-Drivers to be reliable.

Asus's [support website](http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=3&s=101&m=X50N&os=24&hashedid=CebDKwCn6HTAoNXl) for the X50N provides the `2007.03.16` Windows Vista 32-bit update for the **Realtek USB 2.0 Card Reader**. If these drivers do not work, you could also try the latest [Windows 7 64-bit](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=15&PFid=25&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false) drivers (`2011.06.16`) provided by Realtek.